# Solve ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem 
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}=2x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{s^2}\right)^{\!1/2} $$ 
where $s$ is constant and $x(0)=s$.

I want to know how to solve. It is an ordinary differential equation. I tried the method of separable variables but integral was difficult for me.

Help me~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=s \cos{\theta}$.  Then $\theta(0)=0$, and

$$-\sin{\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \sin{2 \theta}$$
$$\implies \frac{d\theta}{dt} = -2 \cos{\theta}$$

This is straightforward to solve by integration; the result is, after back-substitution:

$$x(t) = s \operatorname{sech}{2 t}$$

Comment: Can I put x  into cosine? x can be bigger than 1, though. but it is helpful! Thanks I'll try it again

Comment: $x$ scales with $s$, as you can see from the substitution, so $x$ can be as large as $s$.  I don't know what you mean by "put[ting] $x$ into cosine..."  I just used the structure of the equation to make a substitution that made the integral a bit easier.  Effectively, I outlined an integration by substitution.